# Load and parse XMI file with EMF

Tags: java, xsd, modeling, emf, xmi

I need to load and parse the xmi file(version: OMG XMI 2.4.1) by EMF, but now get stuck.

In [OMG XMI Spec 2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.4.1/), there is a XMI schema **XMI.xsd**, and a **XMI-model.xmi**. So here for instance, I need to load and parse **XMI-model.xmi** by EMF.

What I have done as follow:

- New an EMF project in Eclipse
- Import xmi schema: **XMI.xsd**, and get an **xmi.genmodel** file
- Use **xmi.genmodel** to generate all code in eclipse, it will generate the model code
- New a Junit4 test case and try to load the **XMI-model.xmi** file with **Junit plug-in test** but failed, following is my code.

  ```
  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException {
      URI uri = URI
              .createFileURI("/home/pzhengshuai/Desktop/15Feb-19Feb/XMI-model.xmi");
      _20110701ResourceFactoryImpl factory = new _20110701ResourceFactoryImpl();
      Resource resource = factory.createResource(uri);
      Map<String, Boolean> options = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
      options.put(XMLResource.OPTION_KEEP_DEFAULT_CONTENT, Boolean.TRUE);
      resource.load(options);
      EObject model = (EObject) resource.getContents().get(0);
      Assert.assertNotNull(model);
  }
  ```

The exception is:

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: Feature 'XMIType' not found. (file:/home/pzhengshuai/Desktop/15Feb-19Feb/XMI-model.xmi, 2, 164)
```

Okay, then I tried to read the xsd file and xmi file, I found there is a namespace `xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701"` inside the **XMI-model.xmi**, so I went to the link of the uml space and tried to found the schema of UML. Unfortunately, in this link, all the files about the UML is en format XMI.

So I tried two more option:

1. try to convert **UML.xmi** to **UML.xsd** by using Enterprise Architect, and Altova XMLspy, and do the same stuff above, Failed. Personally, I think this convertion may lost some information.
2. I found a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967112/xsd-for-xmi-2-1-1),

> You can find the XMI XSD on the OMG website XMI XSD 2.1.1 but you will also need the UML Schema and the MOF Schema.
>   A better way to read and write UML XMI files is to use the Eclipse UML implementation. It can easily be used outside Eclipse in a simple Java program : see

I followed the answer and read the documentation about Eclipse UML implementation, but I thought it is not what I want exactly.

So I hope some one could give me some advices. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

From your description I can't tell your exact context, but XMI is usually used as the serialization format (i.e. a "physical schema") for an instance of a metamodel (which is something like a "logical schema").

But what you are trying to do is using XMI as a metamodel, and use XML (with XSD schema) as serialization format. That's probably not what you want.

In order to load an instance of the UML metamodel which is serializied using XMI, just create a resource set and load your `.uml` file using `resourceSet.getResource(uri, true)`. As long as your Eclipse plugin's classpath contains the UML plugin as a dependency, this should work.